# Refuses to use index on TIMESTAMP field

Tags: mysql, optimization, timestamp

I can not understand why the same query on one field uses an index, but not on the other. Both fields have an index. One field is INT and another is TIMESTAMP. Some kind of magic. Help!

This is table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `fb_posts` (
    `postID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `time` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `partnerID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `aTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`postID`),
    INDEX `time` (`time`),
    INDEX `aTime` (`aTime`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
AUTO_INCREMENT=67640377;
```

Explain queries:

1.

```
mysql>       explain SELECT
    ->                 `fb_posts`.`partnerID`
    ->             FROM
    ->                 `fb_posts`
    ->             WHERE
    ->                 `fb_posts`.`time` > 1551107400
    ->                 AND `fb_posts`.`time` <= 1551108000
    ->                 
    ->         ;
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fb_posts | range | time          | time | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

2.

```
mysql>       explain SELECT
    ->                 `fb_posts`.`partnerID`
    ->             FROM
    ->                 `fb_posts`
    ->             WHERE
    ->                 `fb_posts`.`aTime` > 1551107400
    ->                 AND `fb_posts`.`aTime` <= 1551108000
    -> ;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | fb_posts | ALL  | aTime         | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 69567867 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 4 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

WHY???

Comment: Have you tried expressing the boundary as a time string of the format MySQL is accustomed to? (Maybe it is doing some hidden type conversion.)

Comment: See the `4 Warnings`?  Run `SHOW WARNINGS;` right after doing the `EXPLAIN`.  It might just give you a good clue.  If not, I'll ask more `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for both queries.

Answer (score 0):

The Optimizer create the way. They use statistics to find out which way is the
best for this Query.

Try this to see the statistic and read the Manual "PROCEDURE ANALYSE()"

```
SELECT * FROM `fb_posts` PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```